# Googletest on VxWorks 6.6 + / Wind River 3.0

Tags: vxworks, googletest

Has anyone successfully ported googleTest to a real time process in WindRiver 3.0 / VxWorks 6.6 ?

I am able to get gtest to build, but I get a few errors when linking. I can modify these specific sections of code, but that only produces run time errors.

here is what I'm seeing:
googleTest.so: undefined reference to `isascii(int)'
googleTest.so: undefined reference to`gettimeofday'
googleTest.so: undefined reference to `strcasecmp'

I have 2 shared Libraries (.so): 1 for gtest and 1 for gtest_main. I have 1 RTP (real time process) where I have my test code.

Note:
To get googletest to compile in vxworks, I had to modify some of the Flags: Specifically:
GTEST_HAS_POSIX_RE - 0
GTEST_HAS_TR1_TUPLE - 0
GTEST_HAS_STREAM_REDIRECTION 0

Any insight or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the way the Kernel was configured was incorrect.

To remedy the problem, I actually made a brand new kernel; keeping all of the default settings. This worked.

VxWorks is not yet supported by Google Test.
Also note that there may need to be certain changes made to the code to support the platform. For example, getClockTime may not exist and the code have to be altered to use a user defined method.

I think there is a unique solution based on your platform, target and sim; and your development environment. As well as versions of the tool (vxworks / wind-river etc).

Comment: Even though the question is quite old, did anyone succeed to get "gtest" working with DKM applications in vxWorks? Especially version 6.8? With RTP it wors rather smoothly (some modifications were required thoug).

Comment: This answer is unclear to me.  Did you get Google Test working with VxWorks 6.8 or not?  If you did a tutorial would be great of course...

Answer (score 0):

Googletest does seem to be supported on vxworks7

https://github.com/Wind-River/vxworks7-google-test/blob/master/README.md

I have compiled it, and built a DKM, but at the moment it does not seem to be supporting any tests, so I am not sure what is going on there